# Save copy of row in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, copy

I am reading a CSV file. As I iterate through the rows I am changing some data if it is not in a valid format. I want to report on which rows have changed. Rather than check each item it will be much quicker to make changes where required and then compare the initial row with the final row to see if any changes were made.

```
for row in csv_reader:
    tempROW = row
    # make changes to row e.g.
    row["Surname"] = row["Surname"].title()
    # lots more ...  
    if tempROW == row:
      print("No changes to row",row)
    else:
      print("File changed", row)
```

The problem is that no changes are detected because the `tempROW` variable points to the same data.

I have tried `.copy()` but that does not work.
Help appreciated.

Comment: It appears you're using Python, but it's not immediately clear which version. Can you please update your post to more clearly indicate what's wrong and what you mean when you say "does not work".

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
import copy

for row in csv_reader:
    tempROW = copy.deepcopy(row)
```

if you use [dict.copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy) you will have only a shallow copy of your `tempROW` `dict`

Comment: Fantastic thanks. Not sure whether to use deepcopy or just copy. Both seem to work.